# Warning stating "Import 'pywinauto.application' could not be resolved" using python 3.9

Tags: python, numpy, import, pywinauto, pylance

I installed pywinauto  and trying to import it using python 3.9 but there is a warning stating "Import 'pywinauto.application' could not be resolved. Please help me identify the areas of the problem and the cause of it?
Python 3.9
comtype 1.1.14

I tried downgrading the comtype version to 1.1.7 and issue still persists. I also installed numpy package to see if that changes anything but still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your script is NOT named `pywinauto.py` because it imports itself instead of the package.